# Remove duplicates in chat feed curtain

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

Recently the MATLAB and Octave chat room had the tags [matlab-figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-figure) and [matlab-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-guide) added to the feed curtain, which originally only contained [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab). Now questions that are tagged with more than one of these three tags trigger on all related feeds, thus they show up in the curtain twice or thrice.

I therefore suggest a duplicate-filter of such that filters the curtain so questions do not appear twice.

Including the comment by @rayryeng: is it possible to let all separate RSS-feeds feed into a list, which checks for the existence of the fed link within the list? Thus if another tag already triggered and fed the question to the curtain, then the curtain will reject the other requests from other tags on the same question, since it is already in the curtain.

PS: once this happens again I will take a screenshot to include here.

Comment: You may not be able to do anything though. 
Those questions appear in the ticker feed because the questions from those tags have RSS links that tap directly into those tags. Because the questions are being pulled from each tag independently, I'm not sure how viable it is to filter duplicates.  Then again, I have absolutely no experience in web-related stuff, so hopefully someone can correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Use this feed instead? http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=matlab+or+matlab-figure+or+matlab-guide&sort=newest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The situation was solved using the [RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=matlab+or+matlab-figure+or+matlab-guide&sort=newest) as suggested by [@nhahtdh](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308298/remove-duplicates-in-chat-feed-curtain#comment260028_308298) in the comments. This feed chains all the input tags so that each question gets picked up only once by the total feed. Questions tagged with multiple tags are thus now no longer showing up more than once in the feed curtain.