# Duplicates in chat feed ticker

Tags: bug, chat, firefox, rss

There's been a drop-down feed ticker in the [MATLAB & Octave room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/81987/chatlab-and-talktave?tab=feeds) on SO chat for a long time. Last night we noticed that each post started appearing twice in the feed:

[image: screenshot of 2x2 items in the ticker]

The raw RSS feed contains each post once. The URLs in the feed links are identical and contain no protocol header (so if it's due to an HTTP/HTTPS issue, it's not obvious).

Note that we [had a similar problem in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308298/remove-duplicates-in-chat-feed-curtain/) but that was fixed with an appropriate RSS feed link, and this new problem is unrelated (there is only a single feed link set for the ticker).

---

On May 27th I no longer see this issue. I did restart my browser last night, although [the fact](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/81987?m=37277565#37277565) that [multiple users](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/37281125#37281125) saw [the same issue](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/81987?m=37292856#37292856) makes me think these two events are unrelated, and something else changed. Perhaps [some cache has been refreshed](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/), or the problem is only present when there's a higher flux of incoming questions (I find this unlikely, but we'll see on Monday).

Anyway, I saw the problem on Firefox 45.8.0 on Debian while it lasted.

---

The plot thickens: the issue is back on May 27th (Saturday). A user with Firefox 53.0.3 saw the same issue, in the same order of the feed as I did:

[image: newer screenshot]

This makes me fairly sure that the problem is server-side.

Comment: I've been seeing the same thing for a while. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3Aps.png) of the issue and [the current raw feed XML](https://gist.github.com/shepmaster/88f42073bdd3d5159346e83d458c0026). I even tried changing the feed source from HTTP to HTTPS just in case there was some strange redirect happening.

Comment: Status update: as of yesterday (?) we can't see duplicates. Let's hope it sticks this time...

Comment: It's 2021 and it's still happening; see e.g. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/52219141#52219141

Comment: @tripleee regressions are best gressions...